# No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task;

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-storage

In my android studio application, I want to select any picture from the phone storage and then set it in an ImageView **(Using Picasso library for the circular image)** and after that I want to store the image in my firebase storage. But each and everytime I'm getting an **error** that is **mention at the title of the question**. Any suggestion would be helpful for me to proceed further with my work. Below I'm sharing some of my codes and snaps:

**In the console**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.shankhadeep.bloodbankapplication-1kbgca-yu2-dmScRFZxrig==/base.apk!classes3.dex)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.getCurrentAuthToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:148)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:65)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:57)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.sendWithRetry(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:457)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.beginResumableUpload(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:257)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:198)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask.lambda$getRunnable$7(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:1106)
        at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$$Lambda$12.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
2020-10-18 22:21:29.058 26626-27839/com.shankhadeep.bloodbankapplication V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1629870396
2020-10-18 22:21:29.161 26626-28212/com.shankhadeep.bloodbankapplication I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 26626 SIG: 9
```

**build.gradle(app level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.shankhadeep.bloodbankapplication"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-inappmessaging-display:19.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
//    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:16.0.0"
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

**EditProfile Activity**

```
package com.shankhadeep.bloodbankapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.shankhadeep.bloodbankapplication.DrawerClasses.Constants;
import com.shankhadeep.bloodbankapplication.DrawerClasses.NavigationAdapter;
import com.shankhadeep.bloodbankapplication.ModelClass.DrawerMenu;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.UUID;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class EditProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener,
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    EditText Name,Contact;
    Button Edit,Save;
    CircleImageView profile_image,Header_image;
    TextView Email;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 100;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 234;
    ImageView menuImage,nav_button;
    PopupMenu popupMenu;
    Bitmap Img;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    ListView menu_list;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ArrayList<DrawerMenu> al_menu_item;
    DrawerMenu drawerMenus;
    NavigationAdapter nv;
    String [] City={"Select Nearest City","Agartala","Aizawl","Banglore","Bhubneshwar","Bhopal","Chandigarh","Chennai","Delhi","Dispur",
            "Dehradun","GandhiNagar","Gangtok","Hyderabad","Imphal","Itanagar","Kolkata","jaipur","kohima","Lucknow","Mumbai",
            "Panji","Patna","Raipur","Ranchi","Shimla","Shillong","Srinagar","Trivanthpuram"};
    String [] Gender={"Select Gender","Male","Female","Others"};
    String [] BloodGroup={"A +ve","A -ve","B +ve","B -ve","AB +ve","AB -ve","O +ve","O -ve"};
    String [] IsDonor={"YES","NO"};

//DataSettingVariables


    Spinner s1;
    Spinner s2;
    Spinner s3;
    Spinner s4;
    String Donor;
    String gender;
    String city;
    String fname;
    String emailId;
    String contact;
    String bloodgrp;
    String password;
    String image;
    String UserId;
    int flag=0;
    String photo="null";

    //Codes for Data Retrival
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    DatabaseReference mRef,saveRef;
//    Firebase mRootRef;
    FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    ProgressDialog startProgress;

    private static  final  int GALLERY_INTENT=2;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
    Uri downlodUri;
    Uri imageUri;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    MyReceiver myReciever;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_profile_drawer);

        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
        initView();
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        menu_list = findViewById(R.id.menu_list);
        menuImage = findViewById(R.id.MenuButton);
        nav_button = findViewById(R.id.NavigationButton);
        myReciever=new MyReceiver(EditProfileActivity.this,EditProfileActivity.this);
        menuImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        nav_button.setOnClickListener(this);
        unclickable();
        progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
        startProgress=new ProgressDialog(this);

        Save.setOnClickListener(this);
        Edit.setOnClickListener(this);
        prepareNavigationMenu();
        IntentFilter filter=new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(myReciever,filter);
        ArrayAdapter adapterCity = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, City);
        adapterCity.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapterCity);
        ArrayAdapter adapterGender = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Gender);
        adapterGender.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s2.setAdapter(adapterGender);
        ArrayAdapter adapterBlood = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, BloodGroup);
        adapterBlood.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s3.setAdapter(adapterBlood);
        ArrayAdapter adapterDonor = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, IsDonor);
        adapterBlood.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s4.setAdapter(adapterDonor);
        s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        s2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        s3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        s4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        profile_image.setOnClickListener(this);
        preferences = getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        UserId = preferences.getString("GoogleUid", null);
        //  addData();
        saveRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users Details");
        mRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mRef.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                bloodgrp=dataSnapshot.child("Users Details").child(UserId).child("BloodGroup").getValue(String.class);
                city=dataSnapshot.child("Users Details").child(UserId).child("City").getValue(String.class);
                contact=dataSnapshot.child("Users Details").child(UserId).child("Contact").getValue(String.class);
                emailId=dataSnapshot.child("Users Details").child(UserId).child("Email").getValue(String.class);
                gender=dataSnapshot.child("Users Details").child(UserId).child("Gender").getValue(String.class);
                image=dataSnapshot.child("Users Details").child(UserId).child("Image").getValue(String.class);
                Donor=dataSnapshot.child("Users Details").child(UserId).child("IsDonor").getValue(String.class);
                fname=dataSnapshot.child("Users Details").child(UserId).child("Name").getValue(String.class);
                setData();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }


        });

        startProgress.setTitle("Please wait!");
        startProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
        startProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        startProgress.show();
        startProgress.setCancelable(false);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                startProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void setData()
    {
        if(image.equals(""))
        {
            profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);
            Header_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.profile);

        }
        else {
            imageUri = Uri.parse(image);
            Picasso.get().load(imageUri).fit().centerCrop().into(profile_image);
            Picasso.get().load(imageUri).fit().centerCrop().into(Header_image);
        }

        Email.setText(emailId);
        Name.setText(fname);
        Name.setSelection(Name.getText().toString().length());
        Contact.setText(contact.substring(3));
        ArrayAdapter myAdap = (ArrayAdapter) s1.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter
        int spinnerPosition = myAdap.getPosition(city);
//set the default according to value
        s1.setSelection(spinnerPosition);

        ArrayAdapter myAdap1 = (ArrayAdapter) s2.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter
        int spinnerPosition1 = myAdap1.getPosition(gender);
//set the default according to value
        s2.setSelection(spinnerPosition1);
        ArrayAdapter myAdap2 = (ArrayAdapter) s3.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter
        int spinnerPosition2 = myAdap2.getPosition(bloodgrp);
//set the default according to value
        s3.setSelection(spinnerPosition2);
//        if(Donor.equals("Yes")) {
//            ArrayAdapter myAdap3 = (ArrayAdapter) s4.getAdapter(); //cast to an ArrayAdapter
//            int spinnerPosition3 = myAdap3.getPosition(Donor);
////set the default according to value
//            s4.setSelection(spinnerPosition3);
////
////
//        }

    }

    public void initView()
    {
        Name=findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        Email=findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        Contact=findViewById(R.id.txtContact);
        Edit=findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        Save=findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        profile_image=findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        s1=findViewById(R.id.SimpleSpinnerCountry);
        s2=findViewById( R.id.SimpleSpinnerGender);
        s3=findViewById(R.id.SimpleSpinnerBloodGrp);
        s4=findViewById(R.id.SimpleSpinnerDonor);
        Header_image=findViewById(R.id.header_profile);


    }

    public void setClickable()
    {
        Name.setEnabled(true);
        Email.setEnabled(true);
        Contact.setEnabled(true);
        s1.setEnabled(true);
        s2.setEnabled(true);
        s3.setEnabled(true);
        s4.setEnabled(true);
        profile_image.setEnabled(true);


    }

    public void unclickable()
    {
        Name.setEnabled(false);
        Email.setEnabled(false);
        Contact.setEnabled(false);
        s1.setEnabled(false);
        s2.setEnabled(false);
        s3.setEnabled(false);
        s4.setEnabled(false);
        profile_image.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.btnEdit:
                Save.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setClickable();
                break;
            case R.id.MenuButton:
                popupMenu=new PopupMenu(EditProfileActivity.this,v);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
                MenuInflater inflater=popupMenu.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
                popupMenu.show();
                break;

            case R.id.NavigationButton:
//                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
//                        getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
//                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                } else
                    drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;

            case R.id.btnSave :
                SaveFinalData();

                break;

            case R.id.profile_image:  ImageSetup();
                break;


        }

    }

    public  void ImageSetup()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT );
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null)
        {
            progressDialog.setMessage(" Image Uploading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            imageUri=data.getData();
            final StorageReference filepath=mStorage.child("image/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString()).child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
            filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            downlodUri = uri;
                            image= downlodUri.toString();
                            try {
                                Bitmap bitmap =  MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), downlodUri);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Picasso.get().load(downlodUri).fit().centerCrop().into(profile_image);
                            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressDialog.dismiss();

                        }
                    });


                }
            });
        }
    }

    public  void SaveFinalData()
    {
        if(Name.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            Name.setHint("Please Enter Your Name ");
            Name.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else if( Contact.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            Contact.setHint("Plese Enter Your Contact No");
            Name.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else if(Name.getText().toString().isEmpty() && Contact.getText().toString().isEmpty() )
        {
            Name.setHint("Please Enter Your Name ");
            Name.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
            Contact.setHint("Plese Enter Your Contact No");
            Name.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
        } else if (Contact.getText().toString().length()!=10)
        {
            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, "Contact No is not in correct format", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            DatabaseReference currenet_userDb = saveRef.child(UserId);
            currenet_userDb.child("Name").setValue(Name.getText().toString());
            currenet_userDb.child("Contact").setValue("+91" + Contact.getText().toString());
            currenet_userDb.child("City").setValue(city);
            currenet_userDb.child("Gender").setValue(gender);
            currenet_userDb.child("BloodGroup").setValue(bloodgrp);
            currenet_userDb.child("IsDonor").setValue(Donor);
            currenet_userDb.child("Image").setValue(image);
            unclickable();
            Save.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        switch (parent.getId()) {
            case R.id.SimpleSpinnerCountry:
                city = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Selected "+city, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.SimpleSpinnerGender:
                gender = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Selected "+gender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.SimpleSpinnerBloodGrp:
                bloodgrp = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have Selected "+gender, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case R.id.SimpleSpinnerDonor:
                Donor=(String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId())
        {

            case R.id.Logout:
                //FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                SignOut();
                finish();
                return  true;

            default:return  false;
        }

    }

    private  void SignOut()
    {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("user", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.remove("GoogleUid");
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent=new Intent(EditProfileActivity.this,SignIn.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();


    }

    private void prepareNavigationMenu() {

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


        al_menu_item = Constants.prepareSideMenu(this);

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        nv = new NavigationAdapter(this, al_menu_item);
        //stopping  point
        menu_list.setAdapter(nv);


        //Actually we are picking the List_item name from here
        menu_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                }

                //OpenActivity method is called when user click on any List_item of the Navigation Drawer then the User
                //Will be navigated to any other activity...
                new Constants(EditProfileActivity.this, EditProfileActivity.this).openActivity(al_menu_item.get(position).getMenu_name());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), al_menu_item.get(position).getMenu_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

**Firebase Storage rule**
[image: Firebase Storage rules]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firebase dependencies are all out of sync.  You should go through each and every one of them and make sure they are at the latest version, as shown in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  If they are not **all** updated together, then you will see strange errors.

You will also need to update firebase-ui-auth as shown in its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui).

Lastly, you should also completely remove this very old Firebase SDK:

```
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
```